# How to use image processing on 3 1d arrays (lat,lon,val), irregular grid

Tags: python, opencv, gis, geopandas

I have 3 1d arrays containing the longitude, latitude and the data values. The longitude and latitude are irregular and re-gridding is not an option. How could I transfer these 3 arrays to something that I could use simple image processing (opencv) on? The irregular grid is saved in a Geopandas dataframe.

I tried to transfer it to an 2d array, however I get a memory error. I also tried to create a NetCDF file and transfer this to a tiff file, however the grid is irregular. Re-gridding the data at this resolution is not possible due to the size and re-gridding the data to a smaller resolution is not an option.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to use image processing on it when it's not image data? What kind of processing do you want to apply?

Comment: I have NetCDF files that contain satellite data. I have the lon, lat and concentration of a gas (of each 'pixel'). I do have the lon and lat values of the corners of each pixel as well as the centre point. I would like to search for patterns in the data. The size of the pixels vary, that's why the data is irregular.